# JSONObject Response Comparison

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a JSON reponse, like this(given below)

```
{
  "result": "NO RECORD FOUND"
}
```

and I have a response like this

```
okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

if(jsonObject != null) {
  name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("name")
  dlObj.put("dlName", name);
}
```

The condition will execute once their will be some data in JSONObject, but i want a case when the JSONObject has the response like NO RECORD FOUND then it should not go into the Condition checking body, Is their anyway using which i can compare the above mentioned Case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Response code 404?
if so check the response against 404 code

```
if (response.code()==404){

 // deal with it
}
```

Otherwise if you just mean the result property of the JSON object

```
if(jsonObject != null ) {

    result = jsonObject.getString("result")
    if(result.equals("NO RECORD FOUND"){
       //deal with it
    }else{
       //have fun
    }
}
```

if you are not sure the result property is present use hasString to check it before to trying to get it.